# Есть ли в Android функционал, аналогичный CSS calc()?

Tags: android, android-layout

Допустим, мне нужно, чтобы сверху было поле ввода текста и кнопка (на одной строке). Кнопка должна иметь ширину N пикселей, поле ввода должно занимать всё оставшееся на строке место. В CSS это было бы:

```
EditText: {
    width: calc(100% - Npx);
    ...
}

Button {
    width: Npx;
    ...
}
```

А как такое сделать для нативного Android-приложения? Я понимаю, что можно задать ширину динамически (из непосредственно кода приложения), но вдруг есть возможность сделать это средствами XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте LinearLayout и вес для внутренних элементов. Если для них вес не указан, а указан конкретный размер, то он и отобразится. Элементы же с весом распределятся пропорционально.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```